# Why do I get different behavior inside and outside of function?

Tags: r

I get different result when executing this code in a function. What am I missing?

The code that works:

```
adf$GarageCond = as.character(adf$GarageCond)
adf[is.na(adf$GarageCond), "GarageCond"] = "None"
adf$GarageCond = as.factor(adf$GarageCond)    
adf$GarageCond = ordered(adf$GarageCond, levels=c("None","Po","Fa","TA","Gd","Ex"))
```

The function:

```
cnvtNaAndOrder = function(df, colname)
{
  #
  # Change NA's to a "None" factor 
  #
  df[,eval(quote(colname))] = as.character(df[,eval(quote(colname))])
  adf[is.na(df[,eval(quote(colname))]), eval(quote(colname))] = "None"
  df[,eval(quote(colname))] = as.factor(df[,eval(quote(colname))])
  df[,eval(quote(colname))] = ordered(df[,eval(quote(colname))], levels=c("None","Po","Fa","TA","Gd","Ex"))

  return(df)
}
```

Direct execution of the code works as expected:

```
adf$GarageCond = as.character(adf$GarageCond)
adf[is.na(adf$GarageCond), "GarageCond"] = "None"
adf$GarageCond = as.factor(adf$GarageCond) 
adf$GarageCond = ordered(adf$GarageCond, levels=c("None","Po","Fa","TA","Gd","Ex"))

summary(adf$GarageCond)
None   Po   Fa   TA   Gd   Ex 
  81    7   35 1326    9    2 

str(adf$GarageCond)
 Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "None"<"Po"<"Fa"<..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

Execution of what appears to me to be equivalent code through the function results in a warning and different results:

```
adf = cnvtNaAndOrder(adf, "GarageCond")
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("None", "None", "None",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

summary(adf$GarageCond)
None   Po   Fa   TA   Gd   Ex NA's 
   0    7   35 1326    9    2   81 

str(adf$GarageCond)
 Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "None"<"Po"<"Fa"<..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

It appears that the `as.factor()` is giving the warning and not converting "None" to a factor. Note that I have also tried the `df[,"GarageCond"]` form to select the column in the direct execution of the code and it works just fine.

What am I missing?  Why is there different behavior?

Comment: In your function how is adf defined? It is not an argument to the function and there is no definition of adf inside the function.

Comment: Thanks - a simple typo that I could not detect.  And adf was used from my workspace so the error was not clear.  Embarrassing and time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple typo that I could not see.